# Route table flushed - how to repopulate active table without reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, routing, static-routes

I am trying to automate a procedure in our team in which we must flush the routing table on some machines but what I have noticed is that it flushes the active table as well. This table does not repopulate till we reboot the machine and in many of our situations a reboot is not possible.

Is there a way in which a machine with a statically assigned IP address can repopulate the active routing table without 
+ Reboot
+ Shutdown

Is there a way to mimic what happens during reboot (which I am not completely sure of what that is, hopefully someone can educate me on this)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you flush the routing table? Which if not the active routing table do you want to flush?

Comment: I use route -f
I would like to clear out all persistent routes

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? Do you want to get a list of all persistent routes and delete them from the active and the persistent routes? If the persistent routes are always for 0.0.0.0/0 you can take a look at `netsh interface ipv4` and `delete route`.

Comment: I want to be able to flush the persistent routing table only

Comment: `netsh interface ipv4 show route store=persistent` gives me all persistent routes. You should able to delete these with `netsh interface ipv4 delete route <ip> store=persistent`. Therefor my question: are the IPs always 0.0.0.0/0? Then `netsh interface ipv4 delete route 0.0.0.0/0 store=persistent` might work for you.

Answer (score -1):

On macOS you can issue commands:

```
ifconfig en1 down
ifconfig en1 up
netstat -r
```